# Laravel mix generating blank page

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using laravel mix to pre-compile my code. When I run npm run dev or npm run production, I only get a white screen. So i did `git checkout --f public/js/app.js` and then everything work, but when y execute `npm run production`, the white screen appears again.

I also did a video to show what is going on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WkPEdxj4HT4

Also here is my webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.webpackConfig({
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  }
});

// Manage the environments
require('dotenv').config();

// // Enables Browser sync
//  Doc: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-
mix/blob/master/docs/browsersync.md
//  Browsersync: https://browsersync.io/
// Browsersync enables livereloads and live pushes
let proxyUrl = process.env.BROWSERSYNC_PROXY_URL || 'localhost';
mix.browserSync(proxyUrl);

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.version();

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.version();
```

Comment: If you open the browser inspector, does it show any 404s in the network tab, or errors in the console tab? I see you're using versioned assets, so I wonder whether you're not pulling in the correct versioned file.

Comment: It does not show anything. For some reason it starts working after I added the browser sync.

Comment: Your video has been taken down :( Any solution? I'm running into the same issue.